# jquery read one class amount between 2 class

Tags: jquery

i have class named sub , 5 times. and between 1 and 2, and between 2 and 3 and between 3 and 4 i have class named title and i need to know how many times title is between those 2 sub.

i know how to read second sub class
first: ('.page_channel .sub:eq(1)')
second: ('.page_channel .sub:eq(2)')

but how to know, how many class title is between those 2 sub class?

i tried that  $('.page_channel .sub:eq(1)').nextAll('.page_channel .sub:eq(2)').andSelf().length; 
but definitely it not work this way

HTML: http://telekas.herobo.com/test.php

Comment: Could you provide some HTML?  Without it it is hard to discern what you are asking

Comment: sorry, yes i added html.
and i need all div's class amount between second and third sub class..
sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all id must be unique for each element so change **id** attribute to **class** and you can get **title** class div count this way:

```
alert($(".page_channel:eq(0)").find(".title").length) // count of div with class title between first page_channel div and second page_channel div
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ocex1pn1/)

### UPDATE:

For getting between 2nd and third div if you want sum of both divs having between title class use:

```
alert($(".page_channel:eq(1)").find(".title").length  + $(".page_channel:eq(2)").find(".title").length)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ocex1pn1/1/)

Comment: Got to it before I could :)

Comment: sorry, I before made fast some html, what i have in my code. in real code i have class.

but this wont help me? i get yes count of title but in whole body.
i need get title count between second and third sub

Comment: thx, nice. its working, but whi this not working this way alert($(".sub:eq(1)").find(".title").length  + $(".sub:eq(2)").find(".title").length)

i need between second and third <div class="sub"></div> amount and need read using sub class because page_channel class there is a lot more with unnecessary content.

Comment: because title class is not child div of sub use nextAll`()` or `siblings()` :``alert($(".sub:eq(1)").nextAll(".title").length + $(".sub:eq(2)").nextAll(".title").length)`` see :http://jsfiddle.net/ocex1pn1/2/

Comment: your example working yeas, but when i tried in my page, then not working.

can you please watch here, http://telekas.herobo.com/test.php there you see working html , maybe i'm not talked as much as needed

Comment: html is different on the page watch it carefully

Comment: yes, my html in page is littlebit diffrent, but I thought that example what i wrote here, is ok, to understand what i want..but I was wrong . can you please inspect element in browser and help me to get that code work ?

Answer (score 1):

Look I tried this approach : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/xcydys9u/

```js
var divs = $(".page_channel .sub");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 2) {
  var res = [];
  var counterTitle = 0
  divs.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>").each(function(index) {
    counterTitle = $(this).hasClass("title") ? counterTitle + 1 : counterTitle;
    res[index] = $(this).text();

  });

  $("#results").append("Dvis with content :[" + res + "] have .title class -> " + counterTitle + " times" + "<br/>");
  i = i - 1;

  console.log(res);
  console.log(counterTitle);
}
```

```css
.new {
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page_channel">
  <div class="sub title">Content1</div>
  <div class="sub title">Content2</div>
  <div class="sub title">Content3</div>
  <div class="sub">Content4</div>
  <div class="sub title">Content5</div>
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!